# Can/should we use/require node_modules included by my dependencies' node_modules?

Tags: node.js, dependencies, dependency-management

**Scenario**:
*Imagine* you are building a web application using a framework such as `hapi` and you *know* that when you `npm install hapi --save` it installs several "*utilities*" in *it's* [`node_modules`](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/package.json#L20) (*e.g*: [`boom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/boom), [`joi`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi), [`hoek`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hoek), *etc*.)

**Question**:
Can we avoid *explicitly re-installing* `Joi` in the project and use the module included in **`my_app/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/joi/lib/`** e.g: in my `server.js` file:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi'); 
var Joi = require('./node_modules/hapi/node_modules/joi/lib/'); // good or bad idea? Why?

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 3000 });

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{name*}',
    config: {
        validate: {  // validate using Joi
          params: { 
            name: Joi.string().max(40).min(2).alphanum()
          } 
        },
        handler: function (req,reply) {
            reply('Hello '+ req.params.name + '!');
        }
    }
});

server.start(function() {
    console.log('Now Visit: http://localhost:3000/YOUR_NAME_HERE')
});
```

While the idea of not installing the same `node_modules` multiple times appears logical on the *surface* we would like to know the *real* world pitfalls of doing this?

The clear advantage is that when you *update* your dependency on `Hapi` you will also get all the latest versions of its' `dependencies` the potential *downside* is that you won't know when there's a *breaking change* in one of those `dependencies` ... what *else*...?

> Note: I/we do not currently do this in any of our Node.js code, but someone asked me ***why not?*** today and I did not have a *comprehensive answer for them...*
>   "*Because it's bad practice...*" is not a good answer, we want to *understand* ***why***... not have the [*4 monkeys in a room* "*reason*"](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/was-the-experiment-with-five-monkeys-a-ladder-a-banana-and-a-water-spray-condu)